# Can you link your Microsoft account with OS (for app services, etc) but still remain signed into a local account?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-11, user-accounts, microsoft-account

If it matters, this is regarding Lenovo ThinkPad running Windows 11 Pro 23H2 (OS build 22635.3130).

**EDIT:**
Please refer to example screenshot below.  I would like to know if I can sign-in — as to link Microsoft services to the system — but retain the local user account; switching over to using my Microsoft Live Account as the user account disables SMB access from local network, which (from what I understand) is intended behavior by design.

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT 2**:
Specifically, I regularly access SMB file shares over a local home network, typically from Android devices.  I can't recall the specifics, but for some reason or another the file management application I use ([X-plore](https://www.lonelycatgames.com/apps/xplore)) isn't able to pass authentication (states incorrect credentials, despite them being correct, and I've tried all sorts of formats/prefixes/etc.  This was only fixed after I came across a post somewhere that advised using a local user account will circumvent the issue.

Comment: Mostly yes I think.  I just launched the store on a machine with no Microsoft Account.  There may be an issue if you try to buy something.

Comment: can you give us an example of one of the appservices you are interested in? I know that on win10 you can still use the appstore with a local account (if for some god-forsaken reason you actually needed to; mine was minecraft, and I hate them for it) but you do need to login to it first.

Comment: Please note that your title is to be descriptive and is not the entire question. Please EDIT your post, making a complete statement of your situation, circumstances, symptoms, relevant research, etc, and placing the question in the body of the post.

Comment: Maybe, you could create a local administrator to have a test.

Comment: @music2myear I've edited for specificity, please let me know if there are further details I should include.